# How to add constructor to a functional component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a functional component in which i get data from Django REST and I want to manage deleting items. When I write a proper function I get the error

> Cannot read property 'deleteItem' of undefined

I guess it is because I don't have a constructor here, am I right?

This is my function:

```
  function deleteItem(id) {
    axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products' + `/${id}/`);
};
```

And I want to use it here:

```
<Button variant="dark" onClick={()=>this.deleteItem(product.id)} >Delete</Button>
```

Comment: there's no `this` in function components. Perhaps you meant to do `onClick={() => deleteItem(product.id)}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concept  of ***this*** refers to a pointer to methods and attributes in class components that you can access them by that, so you are not capable of use that in functional components , you are able to try followings this:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {

    //...

    function deleteItem(id) {
        axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products' + `/${id}/`);
    };

    return <Button variant="dark" onClick={()=> deleteItem(product.id)} >Delete</Button>
};
```

Answer (score 2):

if it's a functional component then you don't have `this`. You can achieve what you want in a functional component like this

```
function myComponent(){

  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products' + `/${id}/`);
  };

  return <Button variant="dark" onClick={()=> () => deleteItem(product.id)} >Delete</Button>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In functions, `this` depends on how the method is executed.
Yours is a function that runs like this:

```
App()
```

There is no object on which this method is run.

When not found `this` belongs to the global object/window(in case of browsers).
Thing to note is that react runs in strict mode. So `this` is undefined.

You could simply use deleteMethod().

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is a class concept, constructor is a method called when a class is instantiated. Thus functions have no constructors only classes do

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button variant="dark" onClick={()=>deleteItem(product.id)} >Delete</button>
```

Comment: It's good to explain your answer.